# Moderator election voting page "not useful enough"

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

So, the moderator elections have came! Yay! I got an annoying little pop-up on my screen telling me to vote in the elections!

I voted. And now am stuck on [this useless voting page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/vote-moderator).

May I suggest either redirecting the user when they are finished voting, allowing to change their vote, or making the page somehow not just **be there** when I'm done voting.

Maybe a little box on the bottom that says 'Go back', and is disabled until you use your 3 votes?

I just think that ideally the page should say 'Hi! Here I am! Come Vote!', I click on the link, I vote, and then somewhere it should feed me right back into the site.

---

Furthermore, you should probably have each candidates name link to their 'nomination' answer in the SO Election thread, so people who have no idea who the candidates are can know a little more about them before voting.

I'm guessing a vast majority of the StackOverflow community doesn't actually go on meta (or if they have, we've scared them away), and probably didn't see the thread for the elections. So it might be useful to point them there.

---

Just a thought....

*Edit:* Ahh, I didn't notice it does link to their profile. I still think that having a page that doesn't *do anything* once its served its purpose is annoying.

Comment: The name links to the profile.  Some of the candidates have taken advantage of that and edited their profile with relevant information.

Comment: @jjnguy: Why would anyone do that? That's like lying!

Comment: (Kudos for the random order in which the candidates are shown.)

Comment: In related news, I just got the notification even though I voted last night.

Comment: In other related news, I am getting *so many profile hits* right now. I hope they all sign my petition.

Comment: Also: there's no indication of when the election will close. Do I have until I get home tonight to cast a vote? Do I have until the weekend? How quick do I need to be?

Comment: By the way, the voting page *does* link to the nomination thread.

Comment: Choose Jeff's answer already!  Everything that needs to be said has already been said there.

Comment: there's also the matter of every page screaming at you to go vote, after you've already voted, but don't feel the need to subject myself to the certain abuse of making a new post about that.

Answer (score 5):

I sort of like the idea of not linking to the "pitch" provided by each user. Instead, Jeff currently sends you to their record where you can examine their helpfulness, and general behavior on Stack Overflow. Perhaps this was by-design, or just a happy accident, but it seems like a good idea.

That being said, some of the users have taken the liberty to add a small pitch in their profiles too.

Comment: Hey man, do you like lasers?

Comment: I'll give you that. I didn't notice that it links to the profiles, and that is probably a better idea than linking to their nominations. The rest of the question still stands though.

Answer (score 5):

> I voted. And now am stuck on this useless voting page.

How'd you manage to get to this web page, then?

Also, the voting page (if you're logged in, and have the requisite 200 rep) shows who you voted for. I wouldn't call that "useless".

> and probably didn't see the thread for the elections

The meta thread is linked on the voting page. Don't make me bust out hand-drawn screenshot circles on you!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same thought at first, and then I realized how bad of an idea linking to our initial pitches would be. The first few of us who answered (I was, I think, the fourth?) were pretty tongue-in-cheek. Oh, sure, we had our "real" pitches at the top (well, most of us), but we really digressed badly on many of them as they went further. I'm not sure if many of us would want that particular face to be the link. We joked about bribery, zombies, cuss words ... Man that was a fun couple of days!

The profile link is perfect, as Jonathan Sampson said. You have our actual track records, and we are free to edit our profiles to pimp (I mean, *pitch*) our campaigns. I took advantage of that as soon as I realized I was one of the lucky 15 nominees to make the real election.

Answer (score 5):

Not useless!

It is the page that says what votes I have cast.

Comment: This user speaks the truth.

Comment: Why can't I vote my own post down?  I'm not saying anything Jeff didn't say 13 hours before.  Just a bit more distilled, maybe.

Answer (score 4):

> Furthermore, you should probably have
>   each candidates name link to their
>   'nomination' answer in the SO Election
>   thread, so people who have no idea who
>   the candidates are can know a little
>   more about them before voting.
>
> I'm guessing a vast majority of the
>   StackOverflow community doesn't
>   actually go on meta (or if they have,
>   we've scared them away), and probably
>   didn't see the thread for the
>   elections. So it might be useful to
>   point them there.

My pearl of wisdom for anyone running for this moderator job, the gravatar and handle you use will play a key role in your election.

Comment: Ooh. I'm doomed.

Comment: having access to the actual vote results so far, I don't agree. You would think that would be the case (gravatar of pretty girl wins!) but surprisingly it's almost the opposite..

Comment: Are you saying Robert C. Cartaino is in front :) @mmyers I really like your and welbougs avatar and handle.

Comment: @waffles: Actually, I think he's subliminally saying that the serial-killer-looking guy with the cigar is in front. :)

Comment: Well, I personally voted for Jonathan Leffler and for myself, and we both have standard identicons.

Comment: Frankly, I really hope SO users are smart enough to look past our identicons and handles, and use our profiles and their experiences with us (as available) for determining who to vote for.

Comment: @state that does seem to be the case, the results of the previous election were exemplary (Bill and Marc) and I have no reason to believe this election will be any different. COMMUNITY FTW!!

Comment: @jeff: I hope that by, "this seems to be the case," you mean that fat cigar-chomping lunatic is in the lead. I hear that zombies eat brains when they're angry. ;-)

Comment: @state why? your handle and your emotican are definitely part of you. Sure, your profile is probably more important, but if I take exception to some part of your icon, then you're not getting my vote (although I voted blind to icons because my work proxy blocks the site hosting them, so maybe you're ok on that score ...)

Comment: @Unsliced: They are, but they are relatively trivial parts unless they are offensive. The record behind the gravatar and name are what's most important. (That's how I determined my 3 votes!)

Answer (score 3):

It'd be nice if the response bar at the top didn't ask me to vote, when I already have.  Isn't voting tracked by user?

Comment: Exactly what I was just coming here to say ...